# Const lock wrapper for STL containers

Tags: c++, vector, stl, wrapper

I'm trying to create a wrapper for an `std::vector` (or any other container from STL, if possible) that can "lock" and "unlock" the const state of a vector that it's holding.

For example, if I create an object of that wrapper, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    ConstLockVectorWrapper<int> myWrapper(std::vector<int>{});  // Here I pass an empty vector in the constructor parameters,
                                                                // which means that my wrapper will be holding an empty vector

                                                                // By default the vector inside my wrapper is not locked,
                                                                // I can change its size and the values that it holds

    myWrapper.get().push_back(10); // ok
    myWrapper.get().push_back(20); // ok
    myWrapper.get().at(0) = 5; // ok

    print(myWrapper.get()); // Prints 5 20



    myWrapper.lock(); // Now I made the vector inside my wrapper unchangable 



    myWrapper.get().push_back(30); // error, the vector is locked
    myWrapper.get().at(0) = 55; // error

    print(myWrapper.get()); // ok



    myWrapper.unlock(); // Now I can change my vector's size and its values again


    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The only solution (that's not working, unfortunately) I've got, is to create a const reference (`const std::vector<T> &`) and a regular reference (`td::vector<T> &`) inside a wrapper class, and bound them to the main vector in our wrapper class.

So, this is what I've done:

```
template <typename T>
class ConstLockVectorWrapper {
public:
    ConstLockVectorWrapper(const std::vector<T> & vec)
        : wrappedVector(vec), wrappedVectorRef(wrappedVector), wrappedVectorConstRef(wrappedVector), constLock(false)
    {}

    void lock()
    {
        if (constLock) // if the vector is already locked, we just exit the function
            return;

        // else we lock the vector
        constLock = true;
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        if (!constLock) // if the vector is already unlocked (changable), we just exit the function
            return;

        // else we unlock the vector
        constLock = false;
    }

    return_type get() // I need to return a const std::vector<T> & if constLock == true, and std::vector<T> & otherwise, what return type should I put in here?
    {
        if (constLock)
            return wrappedVectorConstRef;
        else
            return wrappedVectorRef;
    }

private:
    bool constLock;
    std::vector<T> wrappedVector;

    // refs
    std::vector<T> & wrappedVectorRef;
    const std::vector<T> & wrappedVectorConstRef;
};
```

Of course, it doesn't work. Just because I don't know what to put in the return type of my `get()` fucntion.

I've tried using trailing return type, didn't work:

```
template <typename T>
class ConstLockVectorWrapper {
public:
    // ...

private:
    bool constLock;
    std::vector<T> wrappedVector;

    // refs
    std::vector<T> & wrappedVectorRef;
    const std::vector<T> & wrappedVectorConstRef;

public:
    auto get() -> decltype((constLock ? wrappedVectorConstRef : wrappedVectorRef)) 
    {
        if (constLock)
            return wrappedVectorConstRef;
        else
            return wrappedVectorRef;
    }
};
```

I can't come up with any solution that will actually work, because I'm not so good at C++ yet.

So I'm asking for your help with my problem. Any suggestions or hints to solve this problem would be appreciated!

Thanks

### PS

My main goal is to make my wrapper container-type-independent, so it can "lock" and "unlock" the const state of the container it's holding, independently of its type.

And here's the `print()` function I used in the first code snippet:

```
template <typename Container>
void print(const Container & c)
{
    for (const auto & var : c)
        std::cout << var << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You can't conditionally change cv qualifiers at runtime like that. Const-ness is something that you specify and use at compile time; once your program is running that information is effectively gone.

Comment: Also, I question the usefulness of a type like this. It seems unnecessarily convoluted to me. What is the practical use you see yourself using this template for?

Comment: I have the same concern as @RedAlert. What real programming style do you think such a wrapper would enable? Would that be code you'd *want* to see in your codebase?

Comment: @RedAlert, I don't see any practiacal use either. I'm in a process of learning C++, and the best way to learn it is to practice as much as possible. When I run out of exercises in my book, I make random interesting problems up and try to solve them. Sometimes I get stuck and ask kind people to help. That's it

Comment: If you feel like you're wasting your time here, I'm sorry. I'm just interested in different approaches to problem solving. And people here are way smarter than me, they can solve about any problem there is. I'm kind of stuck, so I'm just asking for a little help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, a method always returns the same thing. The same type. Every time. It's not possible, in C++, to have a method sometimes return one type, and another type at other times. C++ does not work this way.

So, the initial approach would be to have `get()` return a proxy object with a state. Using, roughly, the same classes and names from your question:

```
class return_type {

      bool is_const;
      std::vector<T> &wrapped_vec;

public:
      return_type(bool is_constArg,
                  std::vector<T> &wrapped_vecArg)
          : is_const(is_constArg), wrapped_vec(wrapped_vecArg)
      {
      }

      void push_back(T &&t)
      {
           if (is_const)
                throw std::runtime_error(); // Or, whatever...
           wrapped_vec.push_back(std::forward<T>(t));
      }

      // return_type will have to implement, and baby-sit all other
      // methods you wish to invoke on the underlying vector.
};

return_type get()
{
    return return_type(constLock);
}
```

This is simple, but crude and somewhat tedious. You would have to implement every std::vector method you need to use in the `return_type` proxy.

A better approach would be to take advantage of C++11 lambdas. This will avoid the need to reimplement every wheel, at an expense of some additional code bloat. But, big deal. RAM is cheap, these days. Instead of `get()` and `return_type`, you will now be implementing two template methods in your wrapper: `get_const()` and `get_mutable()`. Each one of them takes a lambda parameter and invokes it and, if all goes well, passing it the wrapped vector as an argument:

```
      template<typename lambda>
      void get_mutable(lambda &&l)
      {
           if (constLock)
                throw std::runtime_error(); // Or, whatever...

           l(wrapped_vec);
      }

      template<typename lambda>
      void get_const(lambda &&l)
      {
           l(const_cast<const std::vector<T> &>(wrapped_vec));
      }
```

The only thing you now need to decide is whether you need access a mutable or a constant vector, and pick the right getter:

```
myWrapper.get_mutable( [&](std::vector<int> &v) { v.push_back(10); } );
```

`get_mutable()` throws an exception if the vector is locked at this time. Otherwise it passes the vector to your lambda. Your lambda does whatever the heck it wants with it, which can be `push_back()`, or anything else, then returns.

But if you only need read-only access to the vector, use `get_const()`:

```
int s;

myWrapper.get_const( [&](const std::vector<int> &v) { s=v.size(); } );
```

Note that `get_const()` takes care to `const_cast` the vector, before invoking the lambda, so the lambda will not be able to modify it. This will be enforced at compile-time.

With some additional work, it would also be possible to clean this up a little bit, and have the getter also return whatever lambda returns to the caller, making it possible to do something like this:

```
int s=myWrapper.get_const( [&](const std::vector<int> &v) { return v.size(); } );
```

It's possible to have `get_const()` and `get_mutable()` be smart enough to figure out if the lambda returns something, and happily pass it back to the caller, whatever it is. And how to do that, I suppose, will have to be another question on stackoverflow.com

P.S. If you don't have C++11, you can just have `get_const()` and `get_mutable()` return the wrapped vector (with `get_mutable()` verifying that it's not locked). This really accomplishes the same thing. The key point is that due to the way that C++ works, you will have to disambiguate, in advance, whether you need constant or mutable access.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. Thanks for this solution! Although I only know the fundamentals of C++ 11 lambdas, I get your point. But I'm not really familiar with `const_cast` and I can't quite understand what it does in this code. It just forces the user to have a const reference in the lambda parameter?

Comment: You should be able to find a complete description of `const_cast`, and casts in general, in your C++ book. It will have a far detailed explanation of the subject matter than what can be cobbled together into a 400 character comment on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a similar problem a while back. In  multithreaded environment sometimes its more efficient to have different types of lock depending on whether you are reading or writing. But the locking is entirely cooperative. It is possible to obtain a *read-only* lock but still accidentally write to the object.

One solution I am exploring is, instead of obtaining a *read-only lock* from an object, getting a read-only *wrapper* of my object so that not only is the object *read-only* locked it is also only possible to call *read-only* (`const`) methods on the object.

The basic wrapper I used was something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class ConstWrapper
{
    T& v;

public:
    ConstWrapper(T& v): v(v) {}

    T const& operator* () const { return v; } // return const reference
    T const* operator->() const { return &v;} // return const pointer
};
```

By overloading the `*` and `->` operators you get a kind of *pass through* ability to call the enclosed objects methods - but using pointer semantics (though its not a pointer).

```
std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4}; // not const

ConstWrapper<std::vector<int>> cv(v); // const wrapper

std::cout << cv->at(0) << '\n'; // okay at() is a const method

cv->push_back(8); // ILLEGAL!! push_back() is not a const method
```

Comment: `const auto& cv(v);` would also do the job.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sure but it doesn't allow for additional functionality like holding a read-only lock which is released when the wrapper goes out of scope, which was the original rationale.

Comment: I don't see what your wrapper allows that const ref doesn't. Once out of scope, both are unusable. If you want a [Finally/ScopeExit](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/1320/raii-resource-acquisition-is-initialization/4551/finally-scopeexit#t=201608230640322804943), you may still implement a dedicated class for that (1 class, 1 responsibility).

Comment: @Jarod42 I can put a member variable in the wrapper that releases a `mutex` lock when the wrapper goes out of scope. I can't do that with a reference.

Comment: @Jarod42 `Finally` is for legacy work using resources that don't have automatic clean up designed in.

Comment: You may use a `lock_guard` in same scope as the reference. (And the `lock` should also protect the non-const access of the wrapped).  And `Finally` might also be used for restoring state which are not resource (I think about backtracking in recursive function).

Comment: @Jarod42 With all due respect here is not really the place to discuss design. I deliberately left ulterior design considerations out of my example because they are not part of the question.